# Available fonts in MacTeX

Tags: fonts

How can I find out the list of fonts available in MacTeX? In particular, those fonts (say called FONT) which can be used as soon as the command

`\usepackage{FONT}`

appears in the preample.

Also, how can I find out the list greek fonts available in MacTeX?

Comment: The list of fonts for MacTeX is the same as that for (La)TeX --- there's a good list here: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/ and in addition one can access all the system fonts using Will Robertson's `FontSpec` package.

Comment: I suspect the OP meant "available in the default installation of MacTeX" rather than "available for download as additional fonts". There is an incomplete list of the common ones available in TeX LIve in the tables at http://latex.silmaril.ie/formattinginformation/fontuse.html (scroll down). Otherwise check with the TeX Live development team, who presumably have a list of the ones that get installed.