# Specify Font on Pandoc with BasicTeX

Tags: mactex, pandoc

I am trying to convert docx to pdf with pandoc on mac (BasicTeX).  The output font is a serif font and I want to change it to a sans-serif font.

I tried using `-V mainfont=Helvetica` and `-V mainfont=helvetica` with many other system installed fonts, but with no luck.  I get an error `pandoc: fontfamily=Helvetica: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)`.

On the [MacTeX website](https://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html) it says "BasicTeX is very much smaller, and yet has most files, **FONTS**, and programs to process TeX, so this is a rapid way to get a working TeX".

And on this [stackexhange question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149582/available-fonts-in-mactex?newreg=5ec18754c3a64ff0bee8af45f11bef68) someone says all TeX fonts are available for MacTeX.

So I looked up the list of available fonts, and got only errors.

My question is: how do I select the output font for pandoc?

Here is exactly what I tried for reference:

```
pandoc -o Cover\ Letter.pdf -V fontsize=12pt mainfont=Helvetica Cover\ Letter.docx
```

Comment: You are missing `-V` before `mainfont=Helvetica`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the user's guide](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html):

> mainfontoptions, sansfontoptions, monofontoptions, mathfontoptions, CJKoptions
> options to use with mainfont, sansfont, monofont, mathfont, CJKmainfont in **xelatex** and **lualatex**.

That means, that you have to tell pandoc to use either xelatex or lualatex with the option `--pdf-engine=`